# is there any referance of SWAMINARAYAN in Ved, Puran, Upnishad, Ramayan, Mahabharat etc Hindu Shashtras?

Tags: vedas, puranas, upanishads, iskcon, swaminarayan

1. Thay first claimed SWAMINARAYAN as a revolutionary saint.
2. After a little success they claimed him as an Avtar of Shri Krishna.
3. After some time they claimed him to be even higher (SUPREME /
   SARVOPARI) than any other GOD/GODESS.
4. After that they claimed their saints to be above Brahma, Vishnu,
   Mahesh, Shakti, Ram, Krishna and every other Hindu GOD/GODESS.

Is there any legitimate referances of him in any of Hindu Shashtras which prove any of their claim given above?

Comment: No there is no reference. Swami narayan cult is like kabir cult or sikh religion or Sai baba worship. Which means they are non vedic in origin but connected to Hinduism in some way or another. But definitely they are non vedic and non puranic and non traditional denomination equally shunned by Shankar Acharya lineage